# Failed at the node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall script

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, node-sass

I just downloaded the latest version of `node.js` and I've been trying to do `npm install` on one of my projects but saying:

> Failed at the node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall script.

I tried doing: `npm rebuild node-sass --force` which didn't do anything either.

[image]

The error log returns this:

```
3209 warn angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 
but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
3210 warn angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
3211 warn angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
3212 warn angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
3213 warn angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 requires a peer of firebase@^5.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
3214 warn angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
3215 warn geofire@4.1.2 requires a peer of firebase@^2.4.0 || 3.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
3216 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
3217 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
3218 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
3218 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
3218 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
3218 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
3219 verbose stack Error: node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
3219 verbose stack Exit status 1
3219 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Simon K\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:283:16)
3219 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
3219 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
3219 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Simon K\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
3219 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
3219 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
3219 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
3219 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
3220 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.7.2
3221 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\project x\projectx
3222 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
3223 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Simon K\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
3224 verbose node v8.11.2
3225 verbose npm  v6.0.1
3226 error code ELIFECYCLE
3227 error errno 1
3228 error node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
3228 error Exit status 1
3229 error Failed at the node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall script.
3229 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
3230 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

and my npm and node versions are:

```
2 info using npm@6.0.1
3 info using node@v8.11.2
```

I've also tried completely deleting my `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again but that didn't work.

One possible reason for this could be that *before* I updated node I followed this persons suggestion: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10527

Where he says:

> 1. Download and save a local copy of the correct version of node-sass
>      binary - win32-x64-64_binding.node. For example download it to the
>      following location: C:\node-sass\win32-x64-64_binding.node
> 2. Provide
>      reference to the full path of the node-sass binary file in the
>      sass_binary_path npm configuration parameter (in the ~/.npmrc file):
>      npm config set sass_binary_path  For
>      example, npm config set sass_binary_path
>      C:\node-sass\win32-x64-64_binding.node
> 3. Run the npm install command
>      again to install @angular/cli correctly.
> 4. Execute ng serve or npm start
>      and your should be past the problem.

I don't know if this is related.. I wouldn't think so since I've updated node, tried to force `node-sass` rebuild but I don't know.

Any ideas/advice on how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

try this

```
npm audit
npm audit fix
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24218712)

Comment: i had the same issue and audit fix worked for me because there couple vulnerabilities preventing the install

Comment: you saved my life

Comment: Worked for me.. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me too, greetings!

Answer (score 7):

Delete only node-sass folder from node_modules and run following command

```
npm install node-sass@4.7.2 --save
```

Comment: It didn't even have a `node-sass` folder in `node_modules`

Comment: Try this npm install -f node-sass@4.7.2

Comment: hmm.. that might have worked, i get a different error now though.. any idea? https://i.gyazo.com/8ef6c9fdbefe0d6861288d077d95125c.png

Comment: this does not seem to be node-sass error now , try npm install again without deleting the node_modules and post the updated logs.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to do much, you are facing this problem because you are trying to install npm sass@4.7.2 without knowing that whether it is compatible with the version of your pm so the best possible solution is to write the below-mentioned command:

`npm install --save-dev node-sass`

This will install the npm sass on your system which is compatible with the npm version you have.
Thanks, me later
first, go and run the command

Answer (score 3):

Try running using this flag `--unsafe-perm=true`

```
npm i node-sass --unsafe-perm=true
```

Comment: Do you have sudo privledges ?

Try running the same with sudo command

Answer (score 3):

Try to check your Node version. Maybe you are using the wrong version. Use NVM for version management.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I found the solution by reading the documentation of the version of that library, they recommend which versions of node should be used for the installation of that dependency. In my case I changed to node version **9.11.2** using "**nvm**" and after that I ran the command "**npm i**".

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases?after=v4.8.0

[documentation node-sass 4.7.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53rfF.png)

Comment: Thanks for this after trying many solutions this is the one that got it working for me!